# Qbittorrent hogging bandwith even with limits and QoS

Tags: windows-10, networking, router, bandwidth, qbittorrent

I changed ISP a while ago and since then qbittorrent has been hogging all my bandwidth whenever its used and all other devices lose internet.

I have a 500MB d/l and 50MB u/l from my ISP which is twice as fast and my previous ISP but I never had an issue with them, didn't change any settings when I switched ISP.

I've limited qbt to 10MB d/l and 1mb u/l and still get issues where other devices will get connection for a while but then lose it again.

What I noticed that even with the limits in qbt the network usage on the PC for just qbt was over 40mb - is it right to do that? There are no other programs running either.

I tried to solve the bandwidth issue by buying a router with QoS but even limiting the PC itself to 50d/l and 20u/l hasn't helped other connections.

I've tried running qbt on other machines and get the same issues.

I'm lost for what to do.

Comment: How many simultaneous connections do you allow the BitTorrent client to make?

Comment: Ive repeatedly changed it to try and fix things, I think the lowest I went was 8. Though Ive also tried using this site http://infinite-source.de/az/az-calc.html

Comment: Qbittorrent counts speeds in bytes, but Task Manager counts in bits. To convert from one to the other you need to multiply/divide by 8 (actually more than that). Is that perhaps the difference?

Comment: No, I've converted it correctly when limiting; the lower right corner of the main qbt window shows the limits in MB too. Its limited to 10MB down and 1MB up, but Windows shows it as using 40MB network constantly